# how to exit if there is no argument in bash shell script?

Tags: bash, arguments, exit

i have written code to count the number of files and directories, but im struggling to make it exit if no argument is given. here is what i have right now, with the first is statement being the problem. how can i change this if statement to make it exit if no argument is given?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [$# -eq 0];
 echo "no arguments"
 exit 1
fi
cd "$1" || exit
n=0
m=0
for d in *;
do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
        n=$((n+1))
    else
        m=$((m+1))
    fi
done
echo "Files $m"
echo "Directories $n"
```

Comment: Use shellcheck.net to diagnose common errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is: `if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then`.

The spaces are not optional and nor is the `then`. So the beginning of your script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
 echo "no arguments"
 exit 1
fi
```